# Convert PDF to Images

Tags: pdf, converters, acrobat-sdk

Can some one tell using a small sample code on how to convert a multipage PDF file to multiple images with the option to convert to Colored Image (.png) or Grayscale Image (.tif) using Adobe Acrobat XI SDK in C#?

Comment: Do you have reasons to think it is possible? Do you have reasons to think it is *not* possible? Does the documentation say anywhere you can, or cannot?

Comment: yes i know it is possible because I read it in one of their documentations. also acrobat pro gives you an option to save pdf as images which means the sdk should also be able to do so.

Comment: Then you have your answer. "Yes, it is possible."

Comment: edited my questions if this satisfies you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PdfThumbnailComparer.Lib](https://pdfreport.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/PdfThumbnailComparer/PdfThumbnailComparer.Lib/). It uses `Adobe Acrobat SDK` behind the scene to produce images from PDF files" `new PdfToImage { PdfFilePath = "...path to pdf..." }.PdfPageToPng();`

Comment: correct me if i am wrong. what the code does it that it opens a page, copy the entire pages to clipboard, then pastes it onto a bitmap and then saves the bitmap?

Comment: I did some research and got to know that using the api I can call tha save as option for a pdf file. The same save as option is also available in adobe acrobat pro which gives u an option to save pdf as images. Any idea about how to call this using the sdk?